# How can one retain authorship of code even when they are merge it with git squash?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

The owner of the branch gets authorship of all the code event if there are 10 other devs who contributed to the same Pull/Merge Request, if merged with --squash. How can the authorship be retained?

Comment: Use code review process? Github, Gitlab, or in-house Gerrit or reviewboard perhaps

Comment: @mvp Even with that, if you use squash commits with merge using github or gitlab, the branch owner gets the authorship for all the commits.

Comment: "Branch owner" is not a git concept. The problem you describe is a consequence of your *workflow* rather than a technical issue.

Comment: @ShantanuKawale: not true. With proper review process, that becomes impossible. Direct server pushes will be disabled, every single commit will have to go through review process

Comment: Write the authors in the commit log message. You may need a script to collect the authors whose commits are squash-merged.

Comment: [Does the stats include the number of additions and deletions made as a co-author in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828523/does-the-stats-include-the-number-of-additions-and-deletions-made-as-a-co-author)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `git` only way to do this, but github for example introduced the notion of co-authors ([link to docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors)).

If you are specifically targetting github, you can take advantage of this : you will need to generate the list of persons who participated in the PR at the end of the commit message :

> [Creating co-authored commits on the command line :](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/creating-a-commit-with-multiple-authors#creating-co-authored-commits-on-the-command-line)
>
> [*step 1-2: write commit message and add two empty lines before listing co-authors*]
>
> 3 :
> If you're adding multiple co-authors, give each co-author their own line and Co-authored-by: commit trailer.
>
> ```
> $ git commit -m "Refactor usability tests.
> >
> >
> Co-authored-by: name <name@example.com>
> Co-authored-by: another-name <another-name@example.com>"
> ```

---

You can do something similar for other platforms : somehow list the co-authors in the message generated for the squashed commit ;
what will probably not be supported is : having all the co-authors appear in the contributors of the page of the project

Comment: This will help to a certain extent. One still won't be able to track back the author of a line using git-blame will they?

Comment: [Does the stats include the number of additions and deletions made as a co-author in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67828523/does-the-stats-include-the-number-of-additions-and-deletions-made-as-a-co-author)

Answer (score 0):

> if you use squash commits with merge using github or gitlab, the branch owner gets the authorship for all the commits.

Actually, not on GitHub, since Sept. 2022:

> ### [Git commit author shown when squash merging a pull request](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-15-git-commit-author-shown-when-squash-merging-a-pull-request/)
>
> The author of the Git commit created when squash merging a pull request is now shown before merging.
> Previously, the commit author was only shown when merging with a merge commit.
>
> [image: commit authorship]
>
> Also, if the user merging the pull request also opened it and has multiple email addresses configured, a drop-down now lets them choose a different email address to use for the commit's author.
>
> [image: commit authorship selection]
>
> These improvements are designed to ensure Git commits created by squash merging are associated with the correct email address.
>
> Learn more about [merging a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/merging-a-pull-request).